# MVC4 Form Validation not working except from Email validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC4 application, but none of the following Form Validation is working, except for the Email ID one. username and passwords that do not fulfill the minimum requirement can still get registered. Registration is getting dome even if the password and confirm password don't match. Can someone please help?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Web;

namespace ReadingCat.Models
{

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        File = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();

    }
    public int userid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength 
    = 6)]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email ID")]
    public string useremail { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    public string password { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirm password do not match")]
    public string confirmPassword { get; set; }
    public int isAdmin { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
    public string paths { get; set; }
}


}
```

Here is the View code

```
@model ReadingCat.Models.User

@{
  Layout = null;
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Register1</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Sign Up Form by Colorlib</title>

<!-- Font Icon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic- 
 font.min.css">

<!-- Main css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/register.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="main">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="book-content">
            <div class="book-image">
                <img class="book-img" src="~/images/register.gif" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="book-form">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


                    <form id="book-form">
                        <h2>Register Now!</h2>
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = 
  "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group form-input">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "register.css" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new 
{ htmlAttributes = new { @class = "register.css" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-input">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.useremail, 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "register.css" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.useremail, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "register.css" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.useremail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "register.css" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "register.css" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword, 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "register.css" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(model => 
model.confirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "register.css" 
} })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.confirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                        <div class="form-submit">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" 
class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- JS -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out two things; 1) Don't rely purely on client-side validation - you still need to validate the form within the controller. 2) It's a good idea to follow the [Microsoft naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) when possible - in this context, that means your model's properties should really be PascalCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and found the issue that your is missing two required js files.
please add below files, it should work.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

[image]

**you can check live demo using below link**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhxFe7